# Higher order functions in AleaGPU C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, f#, higher-order-functions, aleagpu

I am trying to code C# versions (in C# style) of the F# reduce functions found here:

https://github.com/quantalea/AleaGPUTutorial/tree/master/src/fsharp/examples/generic_reduce

More specific to my question, take this function for example:

```ml
let multiReduce (opExpr:Expr<'T -> 'T -> 'T>) numWarps =
    let warpStride = WARP_SIZE + WARP_SIZE / 2 + 1
    let sharedSize = numwarps * warpStride

    <@ fun tid (x:'T) ->
        // stuff
    @>
```

I'm primarily an F# guy, and I'm not quite sure how I should go about coding functions like these in C#.  For the C# version, the multiReduce function will be a class member.  So if I wanted to do a more direct translation of the F# code, I would return a Func from my MultiReduce member.

The other option would be to "flatten" the multiReduce function, so that my C# member version would have two extra parameters. So...

```
public T MultiReduce(Func<T,T,T> op, int numWarps, int tid, T x)
{
    // stuff
}
```

But I don't think this would work for AleaGPU coding in all cases because the quoted expression in the F# version is a device function.  You need the nested function structure to be able to separate the assignment of certain variables from the actual invocation of the function.

Another way I see to do it would be to make a MultiReduce class and have the opExpr and numWarps as fields, then make the function in the quotation a class member.

So how are higher order functions like these generally implemented in AleaGPU-C#? I don't think it's good to return Func<..> everywhere since I don't see this done much in C# coding.  Is AleaGPU a special case where this would be ok?

A basic AleaGPU C# implementation looks like this:

```
internal class TransformModule<T> : ILGPUModule
{
    private readonly Func<T, T> op;

    public TransformModule(GPUModuleTarget target, Func<T, T> opFunc)
        : base(target)
    {
        op = opFunc;
    }

    [Kernel]
    public void Kernel(int n, deviceptr<T> x, deviceptr<T> y)
    {
        var start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        var stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
        for (var i = start; i < n; i += stride)
            y[i] = op(x[i]);
    }

    public void Apply(int n, deviceptr<T> x, deviceptr<T> y)
    {
        const int blockSize = 256;
        var numSm = this.GPUWorker.Device.Attributes.MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT;
        var gridSize = Math.Min(16 * numSm, Common.divup(n, blockSize));
        var lp = new LaunchParam(gridSize, blockSize);
        GPULaunch(Kernel, lp, n, x, y);
    }

    public T[] Apply(T[] x)
    {
        using (var dx = GPUWorker.Malloc(x))
        using (var dy = GPUWorker.Malloc<T>(x.Length))
        {
            Apply(x.Length, dx.Ptr, dy.Ptr);
            return dy.Gather();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the Alea library, but the F# code is using quotations, so the closest C# thing would be an expression tree created using `Expression<Func<...>>`, but that would be very limited. So either the library has some *other* way of doing this in C# or it is probably going to be hard to replicate...

Answer (score 1):

Higher-order functions are not nearly as ubiquitous in C# as they are in F#. While there are plenty of examples of *accepting* functions as arguments, C# code rarely *returns* functions as results. I guess this is partly because the code comes out very ugly (`Func<T,U>` everywhere) and partly because C# programmers are not generally used to functional style and gravitate more toward OO ways.

In particular, there is no automatic currying/partial application in C#. You can think of it as if all your F# functions always had tupled parameters. In fact, that's how a multi-parameter C# method would look if you called it from F#.

I must also note that the function in your code is *not*, in fact, "higher-order". It neither accepts nor returns any functions. Instead, it accepts and returns *quotations*, which is not at all the same thing. Function is, roughly speaking, a reference to a piece of code, but [quotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) is a data structure. They look similar, but they're completely different animals.

C# does, too, have its own quotations, represented by the type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<T>` (where T must be a delegate type). However, they are *not* the same thing as F# quotations. From F# side, you can (sorta) use C# quotation, but not the other way around.
Both F# and C# quotations have their strengths and weaknesses. In particular, C# supports compilation, F# doesn't. F# supports splicing, C# doesn't.

Which brings me to the next point: *you probably need splicing*. Because you are using `opExpr` in the body of the returned quotation, aren't you?
And C# doesn't have an out-of-the-box support for it. Yes, it is theoretically possible to implement splicing as a library function, but for some reason there is no de-facto standard, regularly maintained implementation. We, for one, had to roll our own. It's open source, too, and pretty straightforward, so [feel free to use it](https://github.com/erecruit/erecruit.Expr#reuse).

Now, having said all the above, I want to express a doubt that you would be able to use C# for this at all. I don't really know how AleaGPU works, but it looks like it expects you to return an F# quotation, which it then, presumably, compiles into GPU code. If that's the case, because C# and F# quotations are two different things, you probably won't be able to return a C# quotation to AleaGPU in lieu of the F# one. Unless it has separate support for it, of course.